# searching for this bibliography style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

I want to have a bibliography style in latex like that:

[Ein05]    Eɪɴsᴛᴇɪɴ, A. (1905). Title. Publisher. etc

Important points:

- abbreviation, last name of author in small caps, then only first letter of first name,  year in brackets directly behind author

I am working with Bibtex and I don't know anything about Biblatex or Biber. 
Is there any bibliography-style which does this?

Comment: You say that you are using BibTeX and that you know nothing about `biblatex` and Biber, and you have tagged your question with both `biblatex` and BibTeX. Would you be OK with a `biblatex` answer or do you want a BibTeX solution?

Comment: Small caps for authors'names is typical of a French style.

Comment: I am okay with a biblatex solution only if it is understandable for me. I never worked with that. So if I know what exactly is to do I'm okay with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fairly straightforward to obtain an alphabetic style with family name in small caps and given name initials with `biblatex`. It is slightly trickier to get the year directly after the name, that is a feature of the `authoryear` styles. So we first load the `authoryear` styles and then use that the `alphabetic` style only overwrites definitions that don't concern the year.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  citestyle=alphabetic, bibstyle=authoryear, sorting=anyt,
  giveninits=true]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\input{alphabetic.bbx}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,nussbaum}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, E. and Ryde, U. (1998). ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

---

If you haven't worked with `biblatex` before I suggest you have a look at [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864), [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864) and [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864).

**You will have to run Biber on the document instead of BibTeX**, see [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) for help with that (and [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) for general hints about BibTeX and Biber).